# SwiftUI Popover Size is not expanding to fit content

Tags: swiftui, ipados

Here is my code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showingPopover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Hello World")
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    self.showingPopover.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                }
                .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover) {
                    
                    List(0..<100) { Text("\($0)") }
                    
                }.padding(30)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should produce a really nice popover coming from the plus button.  But all I get is a really squashed down popover.

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea what I am missing here? Is there a way to tell the popover to expand more (without specifying a size)?

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `ScrollView` and `ForEach` instead of a `List`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingPopover = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Hello World")
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingPopover.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                }
                .padding(30)
            }
        }
        // can be attached to the button as well (as in the question)
        .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover,
                 attachmentAnchor: .point(.bottomTrailing),
                 arrowEdge: .bottom) {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 100) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does work, unfortunately I need the functionality of `List` to remain.

Comment: @SerenadeX The size of the content in a popover defaults to minimum. And such is the behaviour of the List. If you have a List you need to use a .frame modifier. Is there a specific reason why do you need a List? Maybe it can be replaced?

Comment: Nah I would rather just make the frame modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a custom `frame` for the `List`. Also, don't forget to embed List inside a `ScrollView` if you want it to scroll.

```
ScrollView {
    List(0..<100) {
        Text("\($0)")
    }
    .frame(width: 100, height: 250)
}
```

Comment: I guess I wanted it to expand to get the content to fit inside without me specifying a size

Comment: If you don't provide a custom frame it would just default to a minimum width/height. Like you're able to see in your code.